# How to Disable Double Click on the Header of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to do some stuff while double click on a Gridview (Row) not single cell. Means on a double click event handler not on MouseDoubleClick event. But i am not able to disable the header column and row double click event..and also want to load data to combobox(ComboBox is on the same form) when i double click on the GridView Row. Help me Please..!!!

```
private void gvLoadAllData_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick`?

Comment: What do you mean by *But i am not able to disable the header column and row double click event*?

Comment: @RezaAghaei is something wrong with double click event?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Means that if i don't click on row and click on the header i got an error

Comment: I didn't checked `DoubleClick` event of `DataGridView` but when there is a `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` event, surely it's a better option, because if you handle `DoubleClick` and I suppose it also fires when you click on headers, then you should first check if the double clicked location is on a column header or some where else. So why should I leave `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` and bother myself using `DoubleClick`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the info then could you help me with ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126757/discussion-between-kh-aafi-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Just handle `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` like other events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DoubleClick on Row Header**

To handle a double click on row header, handle [`RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    //You handled a double click on row header
    //Do what you need
}
```

**DoubleClick on Column Header**

To handle a double click on column header handle [`ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    //You handled a double click on column header
    //Do what you need
}
```

**Using DoubleClick**

Also if for any reason you want to use `DoubleClick` event, here is what you should write:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var g = sender as DataGridView;
    if (g != null)
    {
        var p = g.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        var hti = g.HitTest(p.X, p.Y);
        if (hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
        {
            var columnIndex = hti.ColumnIndex;
            //You handled a double click on column header
            //Do what you need
        }
        else if (hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader)
        {
            var rowIndex = hti.RowIndex;
            //You handled a double click on row header
            //Do what you need
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I already had `CellDoubleClick` event defined and doing stuff, my issue was that a double click on the header was firing that event and therefore crashing the app.

Taking [Disaster's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261106/2851870), I just added the following to get around that event.

```
if (e.RowIndex == -1) 
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
private void itemsList_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex>-1)
        HereIsNotHeader();
}
```

and bind it to the `CellDoubleClick` event

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It only will be triggered when doubleclick event fired on datagridcell, not header nor empty space(scrollbar).

```
private void gvLoadAllData_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Parent is DataGridCell) DoSomething();
    }
```

Comment: simple and brilliant. thanx.